# Getting error like "Cannot read property 'ext' of undefined" in Jquery Datatable

Tags: datatables

I am trying to show print button in jquery data table. But getting error like  "Cannot read property 'ext' of undefined.

Script which I used are,

```js
script_tag('www/js/data-tables/buttons.html5.js').
script_tag('www/js/data-tables/buttons.print.js').
script_tag('www/js/data-tables/dataTables.buttons.js').
script_tag('www/js/data-tables/jquery.dataTables.js')
```

And css ,

```css
link_tag('www/js/data-tables/buttons.dataTables.css')
```

Comment: please show your html code

Comment: This error usually indicates that you are trying to load a library that is dependent on another one. Usually loading the library in question after all others resolves the issue

Answer (score 6):

Declare the scripts in the reverse order :

```js
script_tag('www/js/data-tables/jquery.dataTables.js')
script_tag('www/js/data-tables/dataTables.buttons.js').
script_tag('www/js/data-tables/buttons.html5.js').
script_tag('www/js/data-tables/buttons.print.js').
```

dataTables extensions wants to access `$.fn.DataTable`.**ext**, which not is present if `jquery.dataTables.js` not yet is included.