# Datatables excel pdf buttons not showing - jquery datatable

Tags: datatables

I'm working on asp.net website using master pages. I want to display data in jquery datatable in my content page but it is giving me an error

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).DataTable is not a function
>
> at HTMLDocument. (StoreInwardRegister.aspx:49)
>
> at j (jquery-1.11.3.min.js:2)
>
> at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-1.11.3.min.js:2)
>
> at Function.ready (jquery-1.11.3.min.js:2)
>
> at HTMLDocument.J (jquery-1.11.3.min.js:2)

script files in site.master page:

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="assets/images/favicon.png" />
<link href="assets/libs/flot/css/float-chart.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="dist/css/style.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="assets/libs/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/libs/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/libs/perfect-scrollbar/dist/perfect-scrollbar.jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="dist/js/sidebarmenu.js"></script>
<script src="dist/js/custom.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/libs/inputmask/dist/min/jquery.inputmask.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="dist/js/pages/mask/mask.init.js"></script>
<script src="assets/libs/select2/dist/js/select2.full.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/libs/select2/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/dist/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/libs/quill/dist/quill.min.js"></script>
```

Script files in my content page where I want to implement datatable and excel, pdf export from databale

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.6/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.6/js/buttons.flash.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.53/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.53/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.6/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.6/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.6/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css">
```

Datatable code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#tblReport').DataTable({
            "ajax": {
                "url": "Helper/DataTableService.asmx/StoreRegisterReport",
                "type": "POST",
                "datatype": "json",
                dataSrc: ""
            },
            "processing": true,
            "columns": [
                {
                    'data': 'Date', 'render': function (date) {
                        var date = new Date(parseInt(date.substr(6)));
                        var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
                        return date.getDate() + "/" + month + "/" + date.getFullYear();
                    }
                },
                { 'data': 'No' },
                { 'data': 'SupplierName' },
                { 'data': 'DCBillNo' },
                {
                    'data': 'DCBillDate', 'render': function (date) {
                        var date = new Date(parseInt(date.substr(6)));
                        var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
                        return date.getDate() + "/" + month + "/" + date.getFullYear();
                    }
                },
                { 'data': 'MatDesc' },
                { 'data': 'TransportDet' },
                { 'data': 'InwardOutward' },
            ],
            dom: 'lfrtipB',
            buttons: [
                'copy',
                'excel',
                'csv',
                'pdf',
                'print'
            ]
        });
    });
</script>
```

It is showing an error in console:
`Datatable is not a function`

But when I write `defer` at the end of `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" defer></script>` Then it is displaying datatable but not showing excel, pdf buttons,
also showing an error in console that

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ext' of undefined
>
> at dataTables.buttons.min.js:8
>
> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Buttons' of undefined
>
> at buttons.flash.min.js:30
>
> at buttons.flash.min.js:8
>
> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Buttons' of undefined
>
> at buttons.html5.min.js:11
>
> at buttons.html5.min.js:8
>
> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ext' of undefined
>
> at buttons.print.min.js:6
>
> at buttons.print.min.js:5

what can be the issue?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35497097/getting-error-like-cannot-read-property-ext-of-undefined-in-jquery-datatable

Comment: I think the print, html5 js need to be first before the jszip, vfs, pdfmake.

Comment: @Jovs but my js files order is same as [Datatable excel export](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/initialisation/export.html)