# Problem for using DataTables in Stimulus framework

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-6, datatables, stimulusjs

I use [DataTables](https://datatables.net/) in webpack ( Stimulus framework ).

I install jQuery and Datatables with yarn:

```
yarn add jquery --dev
yarn add jszip --dev
yarn add datatables.net --dev
yarn add datatables.net-dt --dev
yarn add datatables.net-buttons-dt --dev
yarn add datatables.net-responsive-dt --dev
yarn add datatables.net-select-dt --dev
```

Now I create a controller in Stimulus:

```
import {Controller} from 'stimulus';
import $ from 'jquery';
import 'jszip';
import 'datatables.net';
import 'datatables.net-dt';
import 'datatables.net-buttons-dt';
import 'datatables.net-responsive-dt';
import 'datatables.net-select-dt';

export default class extends Controller {
    connect() {
        $('#data-tables').dataTable();
    }
}
```

When I open page in console show an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ext' of undefined
    at dataTables.buttons.js:42
    at Object.<anonymous> (dataTables.buttons.js:9)
    at dataTables.buttons.js:10
    at Object../node_modules/datatables.net-buttons/js/dataTables.buttons.js (dataTables.buttons.js:30)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:18)
    at buttons.dataTables.js:8
    at Object../node_modules/datatables.net-buttons-dt/js/buttons.dataTables.js (buttons.dataTables.js:34)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:18)
    at Module../node_modules/@symfony/stimulus-bridge/lazy-controller-loader.js!./assets/controllers/datatables_controller.js (cmad_lo_controller.js:89)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:18)
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting error like "Cannot read property 'ext' of undefined" in Jquery Datatable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35497097/getting-error-like-cannot-read-property-ext-of-undefined-in-jquery-datatable)

Comment: Hey user15220416 is this OK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must firs install this packages:

```
yarn add jquery --dev
yarn add jszip --dev
yarn add datatables.net --dev
yarn add datatables.net-dt --dev
yarn add datatables.net-buttons --dev
yarn add datatables.net-buttons-dt --dev
yarn add datatables.net-responsive --dev
yarn add datatables.net-responsive-dt --dev
yarn add datatables.net-select --dev
yarn add datatables.net-select-dt --dev
```

Then use this in Stimulus controller:

```
import {Controller} from 'stimulus';
import $ from 'jquery';
import 'jszip';
import 'datatables.net-dt';
import 'datatables.net-buttons-dt';
import 'datatables.net-responsive-dt';
import 'datatables.net-select-dt';
import 'datatables.net-dt/css/jquery.dataTables.css';
import 'datatables.net-buttons-dt/css/buttons.dataTables.css';
import 'datatables.net-responsive-dt/css/responsive.dataTables.css';
import 'datatables.net-select-dt/css/select.dataTables.css';

export default class extends Controller {
    connect() {
        $('#data-tables').DataTable();
    }
}
```

Comment: If you add
const DataTable = require('datatables.net'); and 
 static targets = ['table'], you can do let dt = new DataTable(this.tableTarget); and skip the jQuery select by identifier, more in spirit with stimulus.